# Hibernate auto mapping of named entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my current Spring Boot REST example project I have two entities (`Book` and `BookSummary`) both provided by an `PagingAndSortingRepository`. The `Book` entity looks like the following:

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
public class Book
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID uuid;

    private String title;

    private String author;

    private String publisher;

    @Transient
    private String type = "Book";

    ...[Getter & Setter]...
}
```

The `BookSummary` entity looks like the following:

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
public class BookSummary
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID uuid;

    private String title;

    private String author;

    @Transient
    private String type = "BookSummary";

    ...[Getter & Setter]...
}
```

The `PagingAndSortingRepository` entity looks like the following:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Book, UUID>
{
    Page<Book> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

The `BooksRestController` entity looks like the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BooksRestController
{
    @GetMapping("/{uuid}")
    public Book read(@PathVariable UUID uuid)
    {
        return bookRepository.findOne(uuid);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Page<Book> read(Pageable pageable)
    {
        return bookRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;
}
```

Regarding the `PagingAndSortingRepository` and the `BooksController` implementation, I would assume that the REST service will provide a collection of `Book` entities via the `/books` route. However the route provides a collection of `BookSummary` entities:

```
{
    content: [
        {
            uuid: "41fb943e-fad4-11e7-8c3f-9a214cf093ae",
            title: "Some Title",
            author: "Some Guy",
            type: "BookSummary"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The `books/41fb943e-fad4-11e7-8c3f-9a214cf093ae` route however provides the `Book` summary (as expected):

```
{
    uuid: "41fb943e-fad4-11e7-8c3f-9a214cf093ae",
    title: "Some Title",
    author: "Some Guy",
    publisher: "stackoverflow.com"
    type: "Book"
}
```

Can somebody help me understanding the following behaviour of Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Hibernate gets confused, because you have named two entity classes with the same entity name by annotating both classes with:

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
```

In this case you should use simply `@Entity` and let Hibernate using unqualified name of the entity class.

It's also a good practice to create one repository per entity: one for `Book` entity, and second for `BookSummary` entity. And I have to say that I have never seen Spring Data repository used for two different entities. Anyway your controller logic could be following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BooksRestController
{
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;
    private final BookSummaryRepository bookSummaryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BooksRestController(BookRepository bookRepository, BookSummaryRepository bookSummaryRepository)
    {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
        this.bookSummaryRepository = bookSummaryRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{uuid}")
    public BookSummary read(@PathVariable UUID uuid)
    {
        return bookSummaryRepository.findOne(uuid);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Page<Book> read(Pageable pageable)
    {
        return bookRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply. I thought that I missed some configuration here, because the hibernate behaviour covers a very common use-case by using the _reduced_ entity for collections and the _complex_ entity for detailed responses. I considered your suggestion and removed the named `@Enity` annotation and added `@Table(name = "books")`. Both entities will have their own `Repository`.